# In how far does/could one hurt himself by giving?

Tags: dana, sotapanna

Beings are act-ually stingy because they think or argue, that when giving this, it will hurt be, be of disadvantage for me.

Now, what does the Buddha mean by advicing to give when it does not harm oneself? Does he even promote stinginess, or what's the game of defilements here?

*(Note: this is not given for trade, exchange, stacks or entertainment keeping in this wheel, but for an escape)*

Answer (score 0):

> In the same way, the pleasure seeker who seeks wealth using legitimate, non-coercive means, who makes themselves happy and pleased, and shares it and makes merit, and who uses that wealth untied, uninfatuated, unattached, seeing the drawbacks and understanding the escape is the foremost, best, chief, highest and finest.
>
> [AN 10.91](https://suttacentral.net/an10.91/en/sujato)